# Thymeleaf loops and iterating

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

this is my template : http://pastebin.com/Gmdmqwxa

Whenever I add comment it is adding always to the first question on the list, even if I click on the others question 'Add Comment' button.However, the remove button works just fine for all the questions.

I think i know what it is working like that, so i thought i could use iterStat or something like that to iterate through questions, and then set th:action with iterStat, but its not working

```
<div th:each="question, iterStat : ${person.questions}" >
   th:action="@{'/newComment/' + ${iterStat.current}}"
```

Maybe anyone has different idea how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Would u kindly share your UI. It will better to figure out error

Comment: @SaifulIslam sure. http://i.imgur.com/iTbhZTd.png and full template - http://pastebin.com/uRPxnd5E

Comment: Observe the Domain of your comments and Questions. 
Double check your given comment is associated for that specific question. If so then we will undergo a deeper observation to your Presentation layer. I am sure your Presentation layer working fine as your remove actions works fine.

Comment: share th:action="@{/newComment}" controller too.

Comment: I've already fixed this by adding helpId field to Comment entity and then just typing id of question i want to answer in 'add Comment' modal. This is not exactly what i wanted to achieve, but i guess ill go with it for now.

    http://pastebin.com/G04kGMGt

Comment: So Your problem was in Domain Layer, not Presentation layer?

Comment: I'm not really sure, i think it was presentation though. It was always taking the first question's id but i dont know why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105900/discussion-between-newbie101-and-saiful-islam).